# Combining chi square charecterisitc

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

I am reading [Statistics by David Freedman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SLB5Q72)

> Suppose the same die had been used to generate the data in tables 4A and 4C
>   (p. 531), rolling it first 60 times for table 4A, and then 600 times for table 4C. Can
>   you pool the results of the two tests? If so, how?

[image]

The author then pools the two tests as

> Pooled $\chi^2$ = 13.2 + 10 = 23.2, d = 5 + 5 = 10, p $\approx$1 %.

My question is, why can't we sum the two table to create new frequency table like this(since same dice is used)

[image]

and then compute the $\chi^2$ statistic with 5 degree of freedom?

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are acceptable. Under the null hypothesis, the frequency table made by pooling the two frequency tables together can be used to compute a $\chi^2_{5}$ statistic. And the method that the author suggests is also correct - under the null hypothesis the sum of the $\chi^2_5$ statistics will have a $\chi^2_{10}$ distribution.

Your question is an interesting example for comparing the two methods because the methods give quite different results. In Table 4A, it seems like there is significant evidence that $3$ and $4$ are the most likely and and that $1$ is the least likely. However Table 4C suggests a completely different distribution: $5$ is the most likely and $4$ is the least likely. By adding the $\chi^2$ statistics together we get a significant result but the large $\chi^2$ statistics are suggested by different deviations from the uniform distribution. If we create the pooled frequency table then the distribution is more uniform - the $\chi^2_5$ statistic is $7.7$, giving a p-value of $0.17$.

I've done some simulations of data generated by fair dice rolls: I generate 60 dice rolls in the first data set and 600 in the second. For each generated data sets I then computed the p-value in two ways

1) pooling the two data sets and then calculating a $\chi^2_5$ statistic and p-value, and

2) calculating a $\chi^2$ statistic for both data sets, adding them together, and calculating the p-value using the $\chi^2_{10}$ distribution.

The joint p-values from the two is shown below.
[image: Pooled p-value vs added p-value]
You can see that it's possible for the added p-value to be very low while the pooled p-value is quite high - one point is an extreme version of the problem that you presented, with two data sets showing very different un-uniform distributions being merged together to form a uniform distribution. Because these deviations from the uniform distributions can cancel each other out, personally I would choose the method that you suggested - pooling the data first and then comparing it to a $\chi^2_5$ distribution. Also, the $\chi^2$ distribution approximation is more accurate for large data sets (Pearson's $\chi^2$ statistic better approximates a true $\chi^2$ distribution as the sample size grows).

Here is the code that I used to generate the plot:

```
set.seed(1)
n1 = 60
n2 = 600
N = 10000
pooledPvals = numeric(N)
addedPvals = numeric(N)

for (i in 1:N) {
  r1 = table(sample(6, n1, replace = TRUE))
  r2 = table(sample(6, n2, replace = TRUE))

  pooledPvals[i] = chisq.test(r1 + r2)$p.value
  addedPvals[i] = pchisq(chisq.test(r1)$statistic + chisq.test(r2)$statistic,
                         df = 10, lower.tail = FALSE)
}
plot(addedPvals, pooledPvals,
     xlab = "Method 2 p-value (added)", ylab = "Method 1 p-value (pooled)")
```